# how to add values of list in scala

Tags: scala

For example list is:

```
case class User(s: String, value: Int)
case class Name(i: Int, users: List[User])

List(Name(1, List(User("A", 1000), User("B", 500))), Name(2, List(User("A", 800),   User("B", 420))))
```

Then how to get output using scala:
 (wanna to add the values: for ex: 1000+ 500 and 800+420)

How to get result in sorted order by value.

Comment: show your case class implementation

Comment: you can't get such result because `Name(1, 1500)` and `Name(1, List(User(A, 1000), User(B, 500)))` has different classes definitions but same names. You can't have 2 classes in a package with the same name.

Comment: any result that should be only sum of values:
ex: 1000+ 500 and 800+420

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that you defined such classes:

```
case class User(s: String, value: Int)
case class Name(i: Int, users: List[User])

val list = List(Name(1, List(User("A", 1000), User("B", 500))), Name(2, List(User("A", 800), User("B", 420))))

val result = list.map(_.users.map(_.value).sum)
println(result)
```

You will get:

```
List(1500, 1220)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can solve your problem with

```scala
case class Name(number: Int, users: List[User])
case class User(name: String, number: Int)

val list = List(Name(1, List(User("A", 1000), User("B", 500))), Name(2, List(User("A", 800), User("B", 420))))

val result = list.map{
  name =>
    val sum = name.users.map {
      _.number
    }.sum
    (name.number, sum)
}

println(result) // List((1,1500), (2,1220))
```